# Are the mid-2012 Macbook Air compatible with older MagSafe adapters?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe

Will the mid-2012 Macbook Air models be compatible with the MagSafe power supply of the previous generations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Electrically yes, physically not without an adapter.

Only the physical layout of the pins and metal end that connects to the Air is different. However, with the [MagSafe to MagSafe 2 Adaptor](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD504ZM/A) ($10) lets any original sized MagSafe adapter slim down to work with the new thinner Mac-side of the MagSafe 2 connection.

Comment: If I would want to be pedantic, I would ask how do you know what the pins are, that the $10 adapter is, indeed, just wires. But, obviously, a $10 adapter from Apple that small can't really contain any power circuitry.